# Solidity transfer funds is redirecting to another address

Tags: blockchain, solidity, metamask

I am trying to send funds in solidity using the below code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract SendEther
{
    function sendAmount() payable public
    {
        address _to = 0x90E3EC58Eb437204ad071339d6CE97740e7eadd0;
        payable(_to).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a entirely different address on metamask wallet

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [0xab29...](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xab297F45caA3FC16Ec18940AfFB1875d2A507056) address that you see in MetaMask is the contract address.

In order to execute the `sendAmount()` function, effectively redirecting the funds to the `0x90E3...` address, you need to send a transaction to the contract address (with the corresponding value of the `data` field of the transaction, representing the `sendAmount()` function signature).

Comment: Can you please share any documentation serving the purpose you have commented

Comment: @ManiDeepakTelaprolu Sure. For example "If the target account contains code..." [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#index-8)... Or "The first four bytes of the call data..." [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html#function-selector).